# menu is hidden inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to show menu on `<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>` click.
I am using bootstrap 3.
The problem is that menu is hidden inside `div`.
I would like to show menu above the `div`.
My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/o9txgsbz/

**Code**:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="media">
        <a class="pull-left" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" src="" alt="Image" />
        </a>
        <div class="pull-right" style="color: #c1c1c1">
            <ul>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="topstory">delete</a></li>
                        <li><a href="findfriends">Find Friends</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="settings">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="logout">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="media-heading">
                <strong>
                    <a href=profile?id=23">ABCD EFgh</a>
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="media-heading" style="font-size: 9px">12/13/14</div>
        </div>
        <div> 
            Hello sdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a few rules:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    top: initial;
    left: initial;
    right: 0;
}

.dropdown {
    position: static;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/o9txgsbz/2/

Comment: some part of menu is going outside the .thumbnail how can we meke in the .thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

Menu is hidden becuase in `media` class element has `overflow:hidden` so when menu appears the overflow part is hidden.
you can give `overflow: visible` to media element to make menu visible.
see this
http://jsfiddle.net/o9txgsbz/1/

Comment: can we open menu in area of media. menu is going outside the media border

Comment: its because in `dropdown=menu` class, `left` is 0. change value of left in css to adjust the menu position.